# Selenium Python = Problem to Click Button "ShowMore" in Infinite Scrolling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm working on **Scraping** Mobile Legend Comment Data in https://play.google.com/. I want my bot to be able to scroll down by itself and load some comment as much as possible. After the bot finish that i want, this bot **Scraping** all the comment.

> The Problem is when the bot do the infinite Scroll down and click the "Showmore" Button, somehow the second click of "Showmore" button gived me error (**[7200:8128:0903/172837.024:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled**) and the looping is `break`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd

#activate GL first
options = Options()
#options.add_argument("--kiosk")#fullscreen
options.add_argument('--enable-webgl-draft-extensions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver', chrome_options = options)
driver.maximize_window()
print("WebGL Activated")

#open google play
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.legends&showAllReviews=true")
sleep(10)
action = ActionChains(driver)

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 10

#this variable limit the infinite looping
click = 0

while not(click == 100):
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        try:
            sleep(7)
            showMore = driver.find_element_by_class_name("U26fgb.O0WRkf.oG5Srb.C0oVfc.n9lfJ.M9Bg4d")
            action.move_to_element(showMore)
            action.click(showMore)
            action.perform()
            sleep(10)            
            print("Click Showmore "+str(click))
            click += 1
        except: 
            print("------Scroll Finish-------")
            print("Click ShowMore Counts = " + str(click))
            break
    last_height = new_height
```

This is output of terminal:

```
WebGL Activated
[5296:3760:0903/174720.883:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [17:47:20.883] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[5296:3760:0903/174720.889:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [17:47:20.889] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:713 GetBluetoothAdapterStaticsActivationFactory failed: Class not registered (0x80040154)
Click Showmore 0
[9052:7864:0903/174913.082:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(441)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled
------Scroll Finish-------
Click ShowMore Counts = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach. Using END key 8 times and clicking show more... There are too many comments tho... Let me know if you'll need any help scraping comments.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile.legends&showAllReviews=true"

d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
d.get(url)
while True:
    for _ in range(8):
        actions = ActionChains(d)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.END).perform()
        time.sleep(1)
    try:
        d.find_element_by_class_name("CwaK9").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very lengthy code. But it keeps scrolling down if `showmore_count` is removed.

Have added relevant comments too.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ucool.heroesarena&showAllReviews=true") # The URL provided in the question was not working for me, so choose this one.
time.sleep(5) # So that the page loads completely
j=0
showmore_count = 1 # Using this to stop scrolling down.
try:
    while True:
        reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jsname='fk8dgd']/div")
        # time.sleep(.3)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", reviews[j])
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-50)")
        print("{}: {}".format(j+1, reviews[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='X43Kjb']").text)) # prints the reviewers name. If j+1 is replaced with j, the Output prints from 0.
        j += 1
except IndexError: # After all the comments are loaded jth element throws Indexerror. And "Show more" button appears. So in except block repeat the process.
    while driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Show More']").is_displayed() and showmore_count <=2:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Show More']").click()
        print("Clicked Show more {} time".format(showmore_count))
        showmore_count+=1
        time.sleep(5)
        try: # Again jth element will throw IndexError, but clicking on "show more" will make it continue. So just pass in except.
            while True:
                reviews = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@jsname='fk8dgd']/div")
                # time.sleep(.3)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", reviews[j])
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-50)")
                print("{}: {}".format(j, reviews[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='X43Kjb']").text))
                j += 1
        except:
            pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

driver.quit()
```

Output is somewhat like this:

```
1: Reviewer name1
2: Reviewer name2
3: Reviewer name3
...
520: Reviewer name520
```